# How can I find whether element exist?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I find whether element exist before using for attribute or if element has label

```
def getidByLabel(self,driver,target_type,target_label,row_position):
    if target_type == 'form':
        attr_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='" + target_label + "']").get_attribute("for")
        return attr_id
    elif target_type == 'table':
        attr_id = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[text()='" + target_label + "']").__getitem__(row_position).get_attribute("for")
        return attr_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `find_elements` returns anything

```
def getidByLabel(self,driver,target_type,target_label,row_position):
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[text()='" + target_label + "']")
    if elements:
        if target_type == 'form':
            return elements[0].get_attribute("for")
        elif target_type == 'table':
            return elements[row_position].get_attribute("for")
```

Comment: Than you..Is it possible to check whether element has label?and then I use getLabelById method to find id?will this solve the issue?I want to return Id using label

Comment: @AkanshaBindal I'm not sure what you mean, `label` in your xpath is the tag, if there isn't any element with this tag `elements` will be an empty list.